# redirecting cmd output to file fails to overwrite when on time interval

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to redirect my cmd output to a text file while over-writing the previous context if the file exists.

```
netstat -e > existing_file.txt
```

using the above code works well overwriting the previous file but adding the time interval of 7 seconds fails to overwrite the file but only appends the existing file.

```
netstat -e > existing_file.txt 7
```

how do I do this while overwriting the file.

Comment: What `man page` are you looking at that makes `7` make sense?

Comment: The command you ran is 100% precisely the same as `netstat -e 7 >existing_file.txt` (except for being incompatible with some non-bash shells, since POSIX sh only requires redirections to be honored at the beginning and end of a command).

Comment: still not working

Comment: The `batch-file` and `cmd` tags are for Windows systems. What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'netstat -e 7' actually does print some data every 7 seconds and you want to overwrite the file with that data each time, you'll need to close the file and reopen it between invocations.  For that, unless netstat provides an option to do it for you, you could do:

```
while sleep 7; do netstat -e > existing_file.txt; done
```

Comment: i get while not recognized as internal command on cmd {error}